How do I add a boolean flag option to a command using System.CommandLine?
I'm trying to add a boolean flag option to my System.CommandLine C#/.NET program. However, nothing I specify when I run the program seems to result in a true value in my command handler:
using System.CommandLine;
using System.CommandLine.Parsing;
using System.CommandLine.Builder;
using System.CommandLine.NamingConventionBinder;

var rootCommand = new RootCommand
{
  Description = "System.CommandLine Example"
};

var exampleOption = new Option<bool>(
  new[] { "--opt", "-o" },
  "Set an example boolean option to true"
);

var exampleCommand = new Command("command", "Example command")
{
  Handler = CommandHandler.Create<bool>((flag) =>
  {
    Console.WriteLine($"Ran example command with opt={flag}");
  })
};


exampleCommand.AddOption(exampleOption);
rootCommand.AddCommand(exampleCommand);

var parser = new CommandLineBuilder(rootCommand)
  .UseHelp()
  .UseDefaults()
  .Build();

await parser.InvokeAsync(args);

When I invoke it, I get this result:
SystemCommandLineExample.exe command --opt=true
Ran example command with opt=False

What am I doing wrong?

It's because you're using a naming convention binder - but you're being inconsistent with your naming. You've specify that the option name is opt, but your parameter is called flag. If you just change your command to this, it works:
var exampleCommand = new Command("command", "Example command")
{
    Handler = CommandHandler.Create<bool>((bool opt) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Ran example command with opt={opt}");
    })
};

From the documentation:

The default convention is that parameters are matched by name, so in the following example, option --an-int matches the parameter named anInt. Matching ignores hyphens (and other option prefixes, such as '/') and is case insensitive.

